# get a set of strings from a text file based on codes in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of codes inside a text file I need to get a set of strings starting from one code to another one.
For example, If I have following data (there could be much more data in between) then I need to get the strings between
     `BS001` till  `ESS01`

```
            BS001 Customer ID|1234|Site Address||||
            SS04,Data LANDMARK HOUSE, LONDON, UNITED KINGDOM|||
            ESS01 ||
```

Currently I was working to read the file and go by each line. But how to take the substring starting from a code to the end of the code  as the end of the code can be in any line like 5 or 10.

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
 {
     string s = String.Empty;
      while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
           SearchStringInaLine(s); // Method to search for ESS01 in the line
      }
 }
```

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The basic answer will be ready at 10:00 am UTC. Would you like a GUI with that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading line by line, you can already get the full file contents into your string by using

```
sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Then you could build a loop and use

```
int bs001 = s.IndexOf("BS001");
int es001 = s.IndexOf("ES001");
string finding = s.Substring(bs001 + 5, es001 - bs001 - 5);
```

plus the offsets of the prvious findings to get all matching text (including line breaks) between BS001 and ES001.